# How to modify local executable search path in powershell?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I'd like to modify the path in the local powershell environment.  At the command line, I'd use:

```
path=%path%;new_path
```

but I can't figure out how to do the same in the powershell environment.  Ideas?

Comment: `$env:path+=';something'`

Comment: *sigh*, I had tried this, but an invalid char somehow got in that I didn't notice.  Thanks @PetSerAl.  Post if you want the cred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%PATH%` is batch notation for variables. In PowerShell you need to use `$env:Path`.

```
$env:Path = "$env:Path;something"
```

or

```
$env:Path += ';something'
```